# Conditional Variables with multithreading

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, condition-variable

I am working on the dining philosophers problem, where n philosophers take turns thinking and eating. I would like to have a version of this where the philosophers will eat in the order of their id: 0,1,2,3,4...,but my threads keep getting blocked. My threads start by calling `PhilosopherThread`().

```
void putDownChopsticks(int threadIndex){
     //finished eating
     pindex++;
     pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

void pickUpChopsticks(int threadIndex){
     pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
     while(pindex != threadIndex){
         pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
     } 
     //lets go eat
} 

void eating(){
     //put thread to sleep
}

void thinking(){
     //put thread to sleep
}

void* PhilosopherThread(void *x){
     int *index = x;
     thinking(); //just puts thread to sleep to simulate thinking
     pickUpChopsticks(*index);
     eating(); //just puts thread to sleep to simulate eating
     putDownChopsticks(*index);
     return NULL;
}
```

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to get the philosophers in order. I can only get the first 2 threads to eat before the threads get blocked.

---

**Edit:** as far as i know im doing this right. I first lock the mutex, then I check if pindex is the current thread id, if its not the thread will wait until pindex does equal the id. Then the thread can go eat and once where done, we incread pindex, signal that the thread is done, and unlock the mutex.

Comment: @jxh, In another method I make n threads in a loop and assign each of them the loop value: 0,1,2,3... (i also made sure it was the correct value). `pindex` should not return to 0, instead it shoud loop through the id values by starting at 0 and going to 1, then 2,3,4... that's why I have `pindex++`.

Comment: @jxh I did another version of this that involved using mutex locks on each chopstick. However now I want to simulate a problem where they eat in order. Meaning normally philosopher 1 and 2 share a chopstick, but now that doesn't matter because philosopher 2 can't eat until 1 is finished eating.

Comment: @jxh I have `pthread_cond_signal` in the first function `putDownChopstick` that way I can signal once the thread is done eating.

Comment: *"as far as i know im doing this right"*, really? Looks more like, as far as you know, your code deadlocks. We don't know, since you don't provide complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code sometimes works and sometimes does not. First, since you did not provide a complete program, here are the missing bits I used for testing purposes:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static pthread_cond_t cond;
static pthread_mutex_t lock;
static pindex;

/* ... your code ... */

int main () {
    int id[5], i;
    pthread_t tid[5];
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        id[i] = i;
        pthread_create(tid+i, 0, PhilosopherThread, id+i);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) pthread_join(tid[i], 0);
    exit(0);
}
```

The critical piece to notice is how you wake up the next philosopher:

```
 pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
```

This call will only wake up one thread. But, which thread is at the discretion of the OS. Therefore, if it does not happen to wake up the philosopher that is supposed to wake up, no other philosopher is woken up.

A simple fix would be to wake up all waiting threads instead of just one. The philosophers that don't match will go back to waiting, and the one that is supposed to go next will go.

```
 pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
```

However, since each thread knows which philosopher should wake up, you could change your solution to allow that to happen. One way could be to implement a separate condition variable per philosopher, and use `pthread_cond_signal()` on the next philosopher's condition variable.

Comment: Wow i have been breaking my head over this and looking at tutorials/websites for 2 days! I'll admit the thought of the problem being the signal never came to mind.

Comment: I was wondering if you could answer a question on mutex? If there are n philosophers, then there are n forks which the mutex will represent. Is it better to use an array of `mutex[n]` or could I simply use two mutex (left_fork mutex and right_fork mutex and share them between the threads).

Comment: My system is very well behaved. I retried your program over and over again manually, never deadlocked. So, I ran it in a script 1000 times, and lo and behold, a deadlock. Noticing that `pindex` did indeed have the right value for one of the waiting threads to continue meant it did not get woken up.

Comment: Well, how would you represent that one philosopher's left fork is the other philosopher's right fork?